AutoMapper - Map from interface to concrete object - unmapped members were found
I'm using the latest version of AutoMapper (13.0.1) and want to map from an Interface to aconcrete object, but I get an exception from AutoMapper (unmapped members (Name, Value) were found.).
If I add a setter in the interface definition (IGroup) for the properties (Name and Value) it works, but it should not be necessary to have a setter for members of the source object.
Any help would highly be appreciated.
EDIT
The problem is configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); --> this throws the exception, however if I remove the  configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); everything works fine, so the mapping does work without any problems but the AssertConfigurationIsValid seems to not work correctly.
Please have a look at the sample below.
public interface IGroup
{
    string Name
    {
        get;
        //set; //it works with the setter
    }

    string Value
    {
        get;
        //set; //it works with the setter
    }
}

public class Group : IGroup
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class GroupEF
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

    CreateMap<Group, GroupEF>();
        
    CreateMap<IGroup, GroupEF>()
      .Include<Group, GroupEF>(); //it doesn't matter if I add Include<> or not.


If I remember well, to create an implicit map you need properties in both side. That means you need the {get; set;} in your interface. If you don't want use the set:, take a look at CreateMap<IGroup, GroupEF>().ConstructUsing(...) or CreateMap<IGroup, GroupEF>().AfterMap((source, dest) => { dest.Value = source.Value; ... })

@Bisjob thx for the fast answer, I hoped there is a "simpler" way of doing it, of course I also could add explizit mappings for Name and Value and remove the setter on the interface, but that seems a little bit verbose.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpl9pC < cannot reproduce.

@Fildor you are, righ!
The problem is  configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); --> I will add this info --> so it seems AssertConfigurationIsValid() has a bug or at least is not behaving as expected.

Still no repro: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3Ba12 even with your exact configuration.

@Fildor I'm able to reproduce it on my end, I will prepare a complete sample, I use Profiles, maybe there is some difference.
Thx for your help!

The problem was in our BasePeofile where we set ShouldMapProperty to a wrong value, which caused this problem.
Thx for your help!
